# SQL Server 2008: NULL SID for WINDOWS_USER in sys.database_principals

Tags: sql-server-2008

Has anyone ever seen anything like this before? I have a WINDOWS_LOGIN AD user that has a record in `sys.server_principals` with a `SID` and can login fine. But in a few databases, they have a record in `sys.database_principals` with a `NULL` SID.

I have scoured Google trying to find out what's causing this as it's causing problems with my SQL Server auditing tools but have had no luck.

[image: The first query is sys.server_principals and the second is sys.database_principals.]

Comment: Sounds like an orphaned user... were these databases restored from somewhere else?

Comment: How can it be orphaned if it's a windows login type and that user has a record in the sys.server_principals table?  In addition running EXEC sp_change_users_login 'Report' doesn't report it...

Comment: Again, where did the database come from? Was it originally on another server? If so, the sid for that server_principal on the other server does not match the sid for the same windows login on the new server.

Comment: The database may have been restored from another server, but that other server would still be on the same domain and all the IDs would be associated with that domain. So this user, DOMAIN\myUser has the same SID on all our servers.  Yet in some databases, there is a entry for this user without a SID.  There are only 20 instances of this happening across 15 servers.

Comment: And has this login ever been invalid or deleted/re-created in AD, or could the databases have been created when the domain controller was unreachable? And you mean login, not user, right?

Comment: Yes, I meant login. And no, I don't think so to any of your other questions. There are other databases that have been restored from other servers that don't exhibit this issue.  In fact, the MSDN site on sys.database_principals basically says SID should only be NULL for sys and INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

If by chance the login was added when the DC was down, wouldn't it generate a SID and put it in that column, and in the case of a recreated AD ID, wouldn't it contain the old SID?

Comment: I'm not saying any of these things ARE THE ANSWER (this is why they are comments, not an answer). I'm just poking at things to look at. The first clue seems to have been a good hunch: these databases did not originate on the server they're on. It's possible when you restored the database to the current server, the user was not validated correctly because the SIDs didn't match, and who knows, maybe that causes SQL to make the SID NULL. Sorry, I don't have much else to offer.

Comment: I understand. Yesterday was the first I noticed them. I do believe that it does have something to do with restoring as well, but like I said, all the SIDs should match.  At any rate, I think I'm going to just remove the users from the databases in question since it's only 23 entries across 15 database instances...